# Изменение чекбокса при событии checked на другом чекбоксе через dom

Tags: html, css, dom

Есть чекбоксы с классом .a и с классом .b

Что написать в html файле в нужном `<input type="checkbox">`, чтобы при нажати `(checked)` на чекбокс с классом `.a` чекбокс с классом `.b` стал `checked` или `disabled` (в зависимости от того, что я напишу)
Через DOM вроде бы как-то это делается

Поскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
  <script>
         function clickCheckBoxHandler(){
            var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('b');
            for(var i=0;i<nodeList.length;i++){
                nodeList[i].disabled ^= true;
                nodeList[i].checked ^= true;
            }
         }
    </script>
    <input type = 'checkbox' class='a' onchange = 'clickCheckBoxHandler()'/>
    <input type = 'checkbox' class='b' />
```

getElementsByClassName вернет NodeList - структуру, похожую на массив, только без методов массива, поэтому перебираем ручками.

И навешиваем обработчик на элементы которые нам нужны.

Comment: `checked ^= true;` это как-то уже близко к конструкциям из [wtfjs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=et8xNAc2ic8).